# How to subscribe facebook webhook event when customer comment to post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

How can i subscribe facebook webhook event when customer comment something to my page post , i try to subscibe page/feed but can't receive any webhook into my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only live and approved apps will receive Page feed events. Therefore you need to submit your app for review (manage_pages permission). After your app was approved you can switch it to live mode and you'll receive the events you subscribed to at your callback URL.